# gcc: what does the `str` parameter do for `__builtin_nan(const char *str)`?

Tags: c, gcc

I was peeking at Apple's [`math.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/ARM/math.h.auto.html) header and found the following definition for NAN:

`#define NAN __builtin_nanf("0x7fc00000")`

Looking at the documentation for gcc I can see that [`__builtin_nan`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fnan) indeed takes a `const char *str` parameter:

> This is an implementation of the ISO C99 function nan.
>
> Since ISO C99 defines this function in terms of strtod, which we do
> not implement, a description of the parsing is in order. The string is
> parsed as by strtol; that is, the base is recognized by leading ‘0’ or
> ‘0x’ prefixes. The number parsed is placed in the significand such
> that the least significant bit of the number is at the least
> significant bit of the significand. The number is truncated to fit the
> significand field provided. The significand is forced to be a quiet
> NaN.
>
> This function, if given a string literal all of which would have been
> consumed by strtol, is evaluated early enough that it is considered a
> compile-time constant.

Can someone (in simple terms) explain to me what `str` exactly does / means in that context?

Also, why did apple choose `"0x7fc00000"` and (for example) [muslc](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/include/math.h) just an empty string (`""`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0x7fc00000" is the representing for the "0x7fc00000"IEEE754. muslc is a light way framework and there for they have a minimalistic approach and set it to an empty string.

Maybe this also helps you:
[Why did IEEE-754 decide NaN != NaN despite being illogical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766368/why-did-ieee-754-decide-nan-nan-despite-being-illogical)

or this

[What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can add a few bytes of information (called a payload) to a NaN that will propagate alongside it and can be used to provide a meaningful diagnostic. They are also sometimes used as a sort of union type by storing a pointer inside the payload (some JavaScript implementations do this).

Here is an excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Quiet_NaN):

For example, an IEEE 754 single precision (32-bit) NaN would be encoded as
`s111 1111 1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx`
where s is the sign (most often ignored in applications) and the x sequence represents a non-zero number (the value zero encodes infinities). In practice, the most significant bit from x is used to determine the type of NaN: "quiet NaN" or "signaling NaN"

> Note: apple's 0x7fc00000 translates to
> `0111 1111 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`,
> which represents a "quiet NaN" with no diagnostic.
> (the difference between quiet and signaling NaNs is that signaling
> NaNs raise an exception before propagating)

Since, in practice, encoded NaNs have a sign, a quiet/signaling bit
and optional 'diagnostic information' (sometimes called a payload),
these will occasionally be found in string representations of NaNs,
too. Some examples are:

- For the C and C++ languages, the sign bit is always shown by the standard-library functions (e.g. -nan) when present. There is no standard display of the payload nor of the signaling status, but a quiet NaN value of a specific payload may either be constructed by providing the string nan(char-sequence) to a number-parsing function (e.g. strtod) or by providing the char-sequence string to nan() (or nans() for sNaN), both interpreted in an implementation-defined manner.

  - GCC and LLVM provides built-in implementations of nan() and nans(). They parse the char-sequence as an integer for strtoull (or a differently-sized equivalent) with its detection of integer bases.
  - [...]
  - musl does not implement any payload parsing

also see this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185406/what-is-the-purpose-of-nan-boxing

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone (in simple terms) explain to me what `str` exactly does / means in that context?

The format for a `float` quiet NaN has the low 22 bits available for use by the programmer.

`__builtin_nanf` interprets the string pointed to by `str` as a numeral. Then it takes the low 22 bits of the resulting number and puts them into the low 22 bits of a quiet NaN.

> Also, why did apple choose `"0x7fc00000"` and (for example) muslc just an empty string (`""`)?

The low 22 bits of 7FC00000<sub>16</sub> are zeros, so these produce the same result, so the choice is largely aesthetic. The format of a positive quiet NaN on this platform always starts with a zero bit (for positive), eight one bits (the encoding for the exponent field that means NaN or infinity), and another one bit (to indicate a quiet NaN). Those form 7FC00000<sub>16</sub>, so using `"0x7fc00000"` is a reminder of what the final NaN will be.

`__builtin_nanf("0x7fc00000")`, `__builtin_nanf("0")`, and `__builtin_nanf("")` all produce the same result.

If you wanted to use this feature for debugging, you might initialize some of your variables with `__builtin_nanf("1")`, another with `__builtin_nanf("2")`, and so on. Then, if a NaN with one of these patterns appears in a later result, you have an indication of where it originated.

(`__builtin_nanf` makes setting the bits of a NaN simple. Reading the bits of a NaN is still a bit of a nuisance. It can be done using `memcpy` or a union.)